# Having difficulty in using flexbox in react native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I have this design that I am trying to make in react native but could not properly arrange using flexbox.

#### Desired Result

[image: The design].

#### My Code

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import Touchable from 'react-native-platform-touchable';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Touchable style={styles.widgets}>
            <View><Text> Hello Dashboard </Text></View>
          </Touchable>

          <Touchable style={styles.widgets}>
            <View><Text> Hello Dashboard </Text></View>
          </Touchable>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Touchable style={styles.widgets}>
            <View><Text> Hello Dashboard </Text></View>
          </Touchable>

          <Touchable style={styles.widgets}>
            <View><Text> Hello Dashboard </Text></View>
          </Touchable>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Touchable style={styles.widgets}>
            <View><Text> Hello Dashboard </Text></View>
          </Touchable>

          <Touchable style={styles.widgets}>
            <View><Text> Hello Dashboard </Text></View>
          </Touchable>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  },
  row: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height:120,
    marginTop: 15,
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  widgets: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    elevation: 2,
    width: '44%',
    marginLeft: 15,
    marginRight: 15
  }
})

export default Dashboard;
```

#### Output

[image: Resultant design]

I think there is something wrong with my approach. It would be really great if anyone points it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `width: '44%'` in widgets style and replace it with `flex: 1`. Also, instead of margin between widgets.

```
row: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height:120,
    marginTop: 15,
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  widgets: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    elevation: 2,
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 15,
    marginRight: 15
  }
```

There is a Expo snack which works within your Expo app: https://snack.expo.io/@vijayst/widgets

Comment: adding `flex:1` in widgets makes them disappear. and if I remove `flex: 1` then the widgets are stuck together with spaces around them

Comment: Updated the answer with an expo snack.